# Android Launcher keeps reverting to system default launcher

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-tv

I'm developing an Android launcher app for Android Tv. When I set my custom launcher as the default launcher it works as expected, but when I restart my device(TV) it shows the old system (TV os) launcher, when I checked the settings I found that my custom launcher is the one set as default.

Any idea what can be the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me also for this i integrated below functionality.

Declare Permission to receive the notification of the boot completion in the application so the receiver gets notified when the device boot completes.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Then declare the receiver as well.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".RunOnStartup"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now in the **RunOnStartup** class open your main activity of the launcher application.

```
class RunOnStartup: BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        /*
        * FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is important because the activity is launched from context outside
        * the activity, without this activity not start.
        * */
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(i)
    }
}
}
```